# Resize Windows in Expo!

Tags: compiz

I love the Expo plugin in Compiz and I use it all the time. But then I realized that on the equivalent feature in Kwin and in Mac OS X, the windows are resized so that they are all visible through the Desktop. I would like to know if it is possible to 
have the same behavior in the Expo plugin for Compiz.

**Thank you!**

Comment: What's a "resized" window? Do you mean *minimized*? What is Expo? *Exposé*?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Expo = Expo plugin. I am not sure if this is the correct terminology but that is how I see it on ccsm. Resized does not mean minimized. It is just resized enough so that they are visible within one workspace. Does it make sense?

Comment: So you're referring to running Kwin on Mac OS X? Or what's the Mac OS reference doing in your question?

Comment: No Kwin and Mac OS X are not related. Maybe I should rephrase the question. What I wanted to ask is: is there a way for expo in compiz to behave like the equivalent feature in Kwin or Mac OSX?

Comment: Ok I did change it... please let me know if you understand my question now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The compiz 'scale' plugin has a feature called 'Window Picker' which is exactly what you're looking for. Turn it on, give it an active corner or a hotkey etc. Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I knew this option. What I am looking for is a combination of window picker and expo. I know that there is an option to have window picker for all the windows. But that is too confusing for me. I would prefer expo + window picker because it would be easy for me to rearrange windows.